# How to prevent the touch event from view to another view?

Tags: android

If I have a scrollview and a subview.
in the subview I add a touch effect so that I can get the touch position.

but the scrollview will also receive the touch event.
how to prevent it?

if I touch the screen from top to bottom to the subview then the page will scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested scroll view instead of scroll view to prevent touch events on it.

Comment: thank you @Yatin Batra  nested scroll view can stop the touch events?